# Android star rating how to fit to width

Tags: android, ratingbar

I need a star rating bar that can fit to width auto. When I try to resize on design screen; if screen is small some stars disappears (after 5th or 6th), if screen with is big all stars are visible.

How do I do it?

here is what do I have

```
<RatingBar
    android:id="@+id/ratingBar1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:numStars="10"
    android:rating="7" />
```

Comment: i havent used RatingBar to be honest, but does it makes sense to wrap it in scroll view, so that usr can scroll if it doesnt fits ? otherwise you may have to write your own control which Different star size based on screen size !

Comment: I'm also having the same issue, did you get a resolution to this issue?

Answer (score 2):

U can't set width but you can use custom Rating bar, just add :

`compile 'FlexibleRatingBar:flexibleratingbar:1.3'`

This rating bar will fit automatically.
Than you initialize for example:

```
ratingBar = new FlexibleRatingBar(this);
    ratingBar.setStepSize(1);
    ratingBar.setColorFillOn(Color.rgb(65,105,225));
    ratingBar.setColorFillPressedOn(Color.rgb(135,206,235));
someLayout.addView(ratingBar);
```